# How to forward packets between two interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, forwarding

My laptop (use's Ubuntu 13.10) is connected to internet using a wired connection at `eth0` with ip `192.168.42.13` and it also acts as a `wifi hotspot` at `wlan0` with the ip `192.168.1.1` (i used airbase-ng to set up the ap). Now I have an android device that needs  to get connected to that wifi. I see that my android is able to connect to the `hotspot` and receive the following network settings from the `dhcp` server I set up. (I used a tool call *Net Info II* from PlayStore to see the below details on my android).

```
# My android network settings (connected to the wlan0 of my laptop):
ip address: 192.168.1.10
subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway   : 192.168.1.254
ap-mac    : xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

# My pc's eth0 configuration
ip address: 192.168.42.13
submetmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway   : 192.168.42.129
iface mac : yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy

# My pc's wlan0 (hotspot interface) configuration
ip address: 192.168.1.1
subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway   : 192.168.1.1
iface mac : zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz
```

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039027/can-not-route-packets-from-one-interface-to-another) talks about a similar problem. I see that I need to forward packets between `eth0` and `wlan0` network to connect my wireless ap's devices to internet. Now *How do I forward the packets I receive from `wlan0 to eth0` and `eth0 to wlan0` to get my device connected to internet ?*

Comment: You might have another problem: why does your Android device list 192.168.1.254 as its gateway? I thought you only had two interfaces in your set-up

Comment: I might not have configured my `dhcpd.conf` properly. I should set it to `192.168.1.1` I guess. Thanks for the correction !!!

Comment: Another thing: do you have a rule in your pc's routing table telling it to use IF wlan0 for the 192.168.1.0/24 network?

Comment: No I dont, How do I add it ? and is it necessary that I add it, since 192.168.1.1 is tied to to wlan0 will that rule be necessary ?

Comment: It is necessary. The command is sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0

Answer (score 7):

You first need to enable IP forwarding on your system. To do it just this once, use

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

or

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

as root. If you want to make it permanent, edit

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

and add a line containing

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

This will be applied on reboot or when you run

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Once that is done, you probably need to NAT connections, as it is unlikely your router knows that the 192.168.1.0/24 network is accessible through 192.168.42.13. If 192.168.42.13 is static, you can use

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i wlan0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.42.13
```

otherwise use

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i wlan0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Check the [Ubuntu IptablesHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) for how to save those rules when rebooting.

Comment: many thanks for your answer, but I am very new to iptables. The way I see your rule you seem to redirect traffic from wlan0 to 192.168.42.13 but am I not supposed to do the reverse as well, to forward traffic from 192.168.42.13 to wlan0. Or is that done automatically ?

Comment: @vikkyhacks When you set up SNAT, returning packets are automatically returned to their proper destination. Netfilter tracks the connections to know which IP originally sent the packet and forward the replies back to that address.

Comment: I couldn't use iptables -i option together with POSTROUTING. This command helped me out: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`