# IP masquerading, rule to forward packets between the Interfaces (on a multihomed network device)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables

## Preamble

This question can be considered as a followup to [link](https://superuser.com/questions/684275/how-to-forward-packets-between-two-interfaces)

## Setup

- **System:** Embedded linux system running netfilter and iptables enabled kernel.
- **Number of interfaces:** 2
- **eth0:** Connected to a NAT which inturn has Internet access.
- **wlan0:** AP mode, Configured with a static IP (192.168.10.1), to which clients can connect to

## Objective

To provide Internet access (through eth0) to the wireless clients connecting to the AP (via wlan0).

## IP configuration and route output

```
wlan0     
    inet addr:192.168.10.1  
    Bcast:192.168.10.255  
    Mask:255.255.255.0

eth0:
    inet addr:10.102.8.93
    Bcast:10.102.11.255
    Mask:255.255.252.0

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.102.8.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.102.8.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

## Steps tried (via a script referred from [link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/firewall-examples.html#RC.FIREWALL-IPTABLES))

```
EXTIF="eth0"
INTIF="wlan0"
echo "   External Interface:  $EXTIF"
echo "   Internal Interface:  $INTIF"

echo "   Enabling forwarding.."
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

echo "   Enabling DynamicAddr.."
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr

echo "   Clearing any existing rules and setting default policy.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F INPUT 
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT 
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD 
$IPTABLES -t nat -F

echo "   FWD: Allow all connections OUT and only existing and related ones IN"
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
#$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -j LOG

echo "   Enabling SNAT (MASQUERADE) functionality on $EXTIF"
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

## Observations

With the above steps, **I am able to ping a node connected in the network `10.102.X.X`from any of the wireless clients connected to the AP (via wlan0, which is in the `192.168.X.X` range) but the wireless clients don't have an Internet connection.**

## Question

For the issue of no Internet, my guess is that the system forwards the packets reaching wlan0 with destination address in the range `10.102.X.X`to eth0 but it does not forward the packets reaching wlan0 with destination address any other other than `10.102.X.X` to eth0. Please let us know your thoughs on if I should add any other rule to accomplish that.

Comment: Can you ping, from one of the wireless clients, 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Your suggestion is valuable. I am able to ping to 8.8.8.8. Does that mean DNS settings are missing for my wifi clients?: How do I get that

Comment: It depends. How do you assign IP addresses to the wireless clients?

Comment: I am running a DHCP server on the AP. I am not clear on the IP that I should use for 'option domain-name-servers' so as to forward the DNS queries to the NAT that is connected to `eth0`

Comment: Yes, but which DHCP server? dnsmasq? isc-dhcp-server?

Comment: ISC dhcp server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26342/discussion-between-vivek27-and-mariusmatutiae).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the DNS for your wifi network. Add, to the file `/etc/dhcpd.conf`, a line like

```
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8;
```

amidst all the `option` lines, then restart your dhcp server and you are done. Nothing else.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. But the question is which DNS server IP should I use? Won't the usage of  Google's public DNS servers slow up the queries ?

Comment: You can use your local ISP DNS if you know the IP

Comment: Okay, thanks I got some handle on this issue. Probably I can try to use the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf |grep -i nameserver|head -n1|cut -d ' ' -f2` to the `dhcpd.conf`

Comment: @Vivek27 No, you shouldn't do that: the way i described is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Marius, Due to some setup issues, I haven't tried the solution. I am just curious to know on what is wrong in the proposed method, i.e reading the DNS server IP from the resolv.conf file corresponding to the `eth0` and using the same for `wlan0`. The clarifications I needed in the method you suggested are: 1. Won't the DNS queries become slower ? 2. Let's say if we want to productize this solution, what is the guarantee that the DNS server IP's won't change. So, wouldn't it be better if we always get the DNS server IP's dynamically via the DHCP server to which `eth0` is connected.